# Getting elevation data in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wcs

I'm using Leaflet map + GeoServer to display a map. I have a TIFF file and a DTED level 2 file.

I created a GeoTIFF store and layer that i'm showing in Leaflet, And I created a DTED store and layer in GeoServer.

I want now to display the altitude of each point from the DEM Layer, like so:

```
Latitude: 32.123 ,longitude: 12.112, Altitude: 12312 m
```

How do I get the altitude data from the store I created?

I tried using WCS protocol but I only get images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can publish the DEM as WMS, and use the `GetFeatureInfo` request to retrieve its value at a given coordinate.
This method was described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230647/129752) already.

Alternatively it might be more efficient to publish a GeoTIFF, if the DEM is small or the amount of values to be requested is high.
When you serve the DEM as GeoTIFF you could use the [leaflet-geotiff plugin](https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff) to extract the raster value at a given coordinate:

```
var map = L.map('map');
var dem = L.leafletGeotiff(url).addTo(map);

map.on('click', function(e) {
  var elevation = dem.getValueAtLatLng(e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng);
}
```

Note that currently only GeoTIFFs in EPSG:4326 are supported.